# User login through token in URL in drupal 6

Tags: 6, users

I have a drupal 6 website and I would like to implement the functionality to allow user of a particular user role to login into site using the token value in the url.

I have user role "SAP" in the website and will send a link to user in mail "www.example.com/user/token". When user click on this link, I want allow user to login into site automatically.

I have searched through into google and drupal site but I did not find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[urllogin](http://drupal.org/project/urllogin) module provides a way to transparently log users into the web site when they follow a link.

Give the “login via URL” permission to users who are allowed to log in with this module.

Alternatively you can try this module also

[Easy Login](http://drupal.org/project/easylogin) allows the admin to give a permission to users so they are able to log in via an url.

Hope it will match your requirement !!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will check this. Do you have any idea about token authentication module? I was checking this but could not configure this properly.

Comment: Sorry no idea !!

Comment: Ok. No problem.  I have checked urllogin project page in drupal and its suggest that we need to use "Token authentication" for the e-commerce site and I need login from url for the e-commerce functionality.

Comment: Where it mentioned i can't see it, it only mentioned 'For accessing RSS feeds' use Token authentication

Comment: Check this -----   If the site contains highly sensitive material or e-commerce, then probably neither module should be used, but a careful use of Token Authentication for a limited part of the site might be possible

Comment: Yes, I have checked that already. I know we should avoid to login through url for e-commerce site but I need to implement this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8787/discussion-between-bala-and-jayendra-kainthola)

Comment: Worth checking this links http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/how-to-embed-username-and-password-in-a-url  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109373/drupal-login-using-parameters-for-login-and-password-in-url

Comment: Sorry, Chat url is blocked in my company. So, I am not able to join you in chat.

Comment: You understood wrongly, you can use both this module for E-commerce site and only the disadvantage using 'Token Authentication' is user can access the limited part of the website

Comment: Ok.. I will try.